# Validate a dataframe based on another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes:

Table1:

[image]

Table2:

[image]

How to find:

1. The country-city combinations that are present only in Table2 but not Table1.
   Here [India-Mumbai] is the output.
2. For each country-city combination, that's present in both the tables, find the "Initiatives" that are present in Table2 but not Table1.
   Here {"India-Bangalore": [Textile, Irrigation], "USA-Texas": [Irrigation]}

Comment: please don't post images of data, use **text** or better **dataframe constructors**

Comment: Have you already written some code that you would like to share with us? Then we can better see where you are stuck.

Answer (score 1):

To answer the first question, we can use the `merge` method and keep only the `NaN` rows :

```py
>>> df_merged = pd.merge(df_1, df_2, on=['Country', 'City'], how='left', suffixes = ['_1', '_2'])
>>> df_merged[df_merged['Initiative_2'].isnull()][['Country', 'City']]
    Country City
13  India   Mumbai
```

For the next question, we first need to remove the `NaN` rows from the previously merged `DataFrame` :

```py
>>> df_both_table = df_merged[~df_merged['Initiative_2'].isnull()]
>>> df_both_table
    Country City        Initiative_1    Initiative_2
0   India   Bangalore   Plants          Plants
1   India   Bangalore   Plants          Textile
2   India   Bangalore   Plants          Irrigtion
3   India   Bangalore   Industries      Plants
4   India   Bangalore   Industries      Textile
5   India   Bangalore   Industries      Irrigtion
6   India   Bangalore   Roads           Plants
7   India   Bangalore   Roads           Textile
8   India   Bangalore   Roads           Irrigtion
9   USA     Texas       Plants          Plants
10  USA     Texas       Plants          Irrigation
11  USA     Texas       Roads           Plants
12  USA     Texas       Roads           Irrigation
```

Then, we can filter on the rows that are strictly different on columns `Initiative_1` and `Initiative_2` and use a `groupby` to get the list of `Innitiative_2` :

```py
>>> df_unique_initiative_2 = df_both_table[~(df_both_table['Initiative_1'] == df_both_table['Initiative_2'])]
>>> df_list_initiative_2 = df_unique_initiative_2.groupby(['Country', 'City'])['Initiative_2'].unique().reset_index()
>>> df_list_initiative_2
    Country City        Initiative_2
0   India   Bangalore   [Textile, Irrigation, Plants]
1   USA     Texas       [Irrigation, Plants]
```

We do the same but this time on `Initiative_1` to get the list as well :

```py
>>> df_list_initiative_1 = df_unique_initiative_2.groupby(['Country', 'City'])['Initiative_1'].unique().reset_index()
>>> df_list_initiative_1
    Country City        Initiative_1
0   India   Bangalore   [Plants, Industries, Roads]
1   USA     Texas       [Plants, Roads]
```

To finish, we use the `set` to remove the last redondant `Initiative_1` elements to get the expected result :

```py
>>> df_list_initiative_2['Initiative'] = (df_list_initiative_2['Initiative_2'].map(set)-df_list_initiative_1['Initiative_1'].map(set)).map(list)
>>> df_list_initiative_2[['Country', 'City', 'Initiative']]
    Country City        Initiative
0   India   Bangalore   [Textile, Irrigation]
1   USA     Texas       [Irrigation]
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach (`df1` your `Table1`, `df2` your `Table2`):

```
combos_1, combos_2 = set(zip(df1.Country, df1.City)), set(zip(df2.Country, df2.City))
in_2_but_not_in_1 = [f"{country}-{city}" for country, city in combos_2 - combos_1]
initiatives = {
    f"{country}-{city}": (
        set(df2.Initiative[df2.Country.eq(country) & df2.City.eq(city)])
        - set(df1.Initiative[df1.Country.eq(country) & df1.City.eq(city)])
    )
    for country, city in combos_1 & combos_2
}
```

Results:

```
['India-Delhi']
{'India-Bangalore': {'Irrigation', 'Textile'}, 'USA-Texas': {'Irrigation'}}
```

I think you got this *"The country-city combinations that are present only in Table2 but not Table1. Here [India-Mumbai] is the output"* wrong: The combinations `India-Mumbai` is *not*  present in `Table2`?

Comment: Very nice and pythonic usage of comprehension list and dict, I like this approche ! Thanks @Timus.

Comment: @tlentali Thanks! I had built a Pandas-centered answer, but when I was about to post it I saw yours, which is pretty similar to my first attempt. So I decided to do something different.